# Rows to Columns Using Dynamic Query

Tags: sql

Hi I have a Scenario were i need to Create a Columns Dynamically Based on the Result set.

[Table Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZPua.jpg)

Expected Result:

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXD2y.jpg)

Using Pivot Kindly Help me to get the same.Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated a [pivot version](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c118bf/6/0)

How about put the result as JSON (or something else) to the fixed column?

```
| **Retailer_Name** | **Distributor_Name ** | **Seller_Name **                 
| ----------------- | --------------------- |
| Store1            | Dist1                 | [{Seller_Name: [Seller1,Seller2,Seller3]}] |
```

Comment: Hi How can i achieve this By using Json data??

Comment: Hi Thanks for the Comments But in my case i Need to get it By SQL Query Using PIVOT.

Comment: I had make a PIVOT version

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot  for the Immediate Response ,.Let me try from my end and update you on this.